# android - json generated listview onClick only shows last item

Tags: android, json, google-maps, listview, onclick

I have a map which shows markers from json file from web.
    I made a search listview from the same file. 
    What I want to do is after click on any result map zooms on the marker associated with that result.
    But now when I click on any result it only zoom on ONE marker which is the last item in my json file.

Here's my code:

```
    public class MapAcWithMarker extends FragmentActivity
            implements OnMapReadyCallback {

        static final LatLng TEHRAN = new LatLng(35.697291, 51.392378);
        private GoogleMap mMap;
        public ArrayList<Locations> locationsList;
        public ListView listView;
        private View parentView;
        public DataAdapter adapter;
        ArrayList<Locations> arrayListTemp=new ArrayList<>();
        EditText inputSearch;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_recyc);
            // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
            final SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
            //  AsyncTaskGetMarker asyncTaskGetMareker= new AsyncTaskGetMarker();
            new AsyncTaskGetMarker().execute();

            locationsList = new ArrayList<>();
            parentView = findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
            inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


            inputSearch.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                    if(keyCode== KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){
                        listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }


                    return true;
                }
            });

            inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int count) {

                    listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    if(count==0){
                        listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    }
                    String searchString= inputSearch.getText()
                            .toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                    int realText= searchString.length();
                    arrayListTemp.clear();
                    for (int i =0 ; i <locationsList.size(); i++){
                        try {
                            String pname= locationsList.get(i).getPname()
                                    .toString();

                            String bicycleno= locationsList.get(i).getBicycleno()
                                    .toString();

                            if(realText<=pname.length() && realText<= bicycleno.length())

                                if (searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(pname.substring(0,
                                        realText)) ||
                                        searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(bicycleno.substring(0, realText))

                                        ) {

                                    arrayListTemp.add(locationsList.get(i));

                                } else {
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
 Log.d("@w2w2w2w","arrayListTemp size is "+arrayListTemp.size());
  adapter = new DataAdapter(MapAcWithMarker.this, arrayListTemp);
  listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                              int arg3) {
                }



                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {


                }
            });
            RequestInterface api = JsonClient.getApiService();

            /**
             * Calling JSON
             */
            Call<StopList> call = api.getJSON();

            /**
             * Enqueue Callback will be call when get response...
             */
            call.enqueue(new Callback<StopList>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<StopList> call, Response<StopList> response) {
                    //Dismiss Dialog
                    //  dialog.dismiss();

                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        /**
                         * Got Successfully
                         */
                        locationsList = response.body().getLocations();

                        /**
                         * Binding that List to Adapter
                         */
                        adapter = new DataAdapter(MapAcWithMarker.this,
                                locationsList);
                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<StopList> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }




        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap = googleMap;
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(TEHRAN, 10));

            new AsyncTaskGetMarker().execute();
        }




        class AsyncTaskGetMarker extends
                AsyncTask<String, String, JSONArray> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) {

                String json = null;
                JSONArray jsonarray = null;
                HttpURLConnection conn = null;
                BufferedReader reader = null;
                try {

                    URL url = new URL("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1879ab.json");
                    conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.connect();
                    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                    reader = new BufferedReader
                            (new InputStreamReader(in));

                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        builder.append(line);
                    }
                    reader.close();
                    String response = builder.toString();
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    jsonarray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("stops");
                    // jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return jsonarray;
            }


           protected void onPostExecute(final JSONArray jsonarray) {
            try {
                final SparseArray<LatLng> positions =
                        new SparseArray<>();
                mMap.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String name = obj.getString("name");
                    String pname = obj.getString("pname");
                    String bicycleno = obj.getString("bicycleno");

                    Double lat = obj.getDouble("lat");
                    Double lang = obj.getDouble("lang");
                    final LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lang);

                    String title = "name: " + name;
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(position).title(title));

                    positions.put(i, position);

}
                    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                            if (positions.get(position) != null)
                                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(positions.get(position), 15));

                        }
                    });


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }



        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

inside `onPostExecute` you have:

```
position = new LatLng(lat, lang);
String title = "name: " + name;

mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(position).title(title));
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position,15));
                    }
                });
```

so under `position` you have always last called position. This variable is used by every `onClick` set (in line: `newLatLngZoom(position,15)`)

for fix this create `position` only locally inside method, you don`t need global`LatLng position` variable declared on top of file

```
final LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lang);
//rest of code as above
```

edit: also these

```
lat = obj.getDouble("lat");
lang = obj.getDouble("lang");
```

keep them local only inside one loop of `for` inside `onPostExecute`

```
Double lat = obj.getDouble("lat");
Double lang = obj.getDouble("lang");
```

you should remove these declarations inside `MapAcWithMarker` class (on top)

```
//below to remove
public Double lat;
public Double lang;
public LatLng position;
//these are not used anywhere
public int selectionId= -1;
Marker markers;
```

next edit:

whole code of postExecute method

```
protected void onPostExecute(final JSONArray jsonarray) {
    try{
        final SparseArray<LatLng> positions = new SparseArray<>();
        mMap.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

            String name = obj.getString("name");
            String pname = obj.getString("pname");
            String bicycleno = obj.getString("bicycleno");

            Double lat = obj.getDouble("lat");
            Double lang = obj.getDouble("lang");

            final LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lang);
            String title = "name: " + name;

            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(position).title(title));

            positions.put(i, position);
        }

        // set once, outside for loop
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                if(positions.get(position)!=null)
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(positions.get(position),15));
            }
        });
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I've inspected your code more carefully and... is a mess. you are not notifying adapter about new data/json (even if data in adapter matching parsed json on positions, titles etc. you should refresh layout). also every objects parsed from JSON are added to map as a `Marker` with `mMap.addMarker(...)` method, but I don't see any `mMap.clear();` method called, so points may duplicate, when JSON is downloaded again (added this line above)

another edit - you have only one item drawn on list because you have inside `onTextChanged` method

```
for (int i =0 ; i <locationsList.size(); i++){
    ...
    adapter = new DataAdapter(MapAcWithMarker.this, arrayListTemp);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    ...
}
```

creation of adapter should be done once, outside `for` loop. check after loop but before initiation that `arrayListTemp` have more items

```
for (int i =0 ; i <locationsList.size(); i++){
    ...
}

Log.d("@w2w2w2w","arrayListTemp size is "+arrayListTemp.size());
adapter = new DataAdapter(MapAcWithMarker.this, arrayListTemp);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

lot of bugs...

Comment: I put  final `LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lang);` in the onPostExecute method. but it didn't work

Comment: edit your question with current code and we will see whats next :)

Comment: `lat = obj.getDouble("lat");` and `lang = obj.getDouble("lang");` are still globally declared and last values are stored in all different `LatLng position` created locally. both lines shoud have `Double` "prefix", be "local" only

Comment: I deleted the global values and declared `Double` inside the method.

Comment: check out my last edit, there is more to do in your code that you think...

Comment: First thank you for your time and help. I'm still learning android & java and because of that my code is so messy :( . I updated my code to the last version of your edit but it only shows the first location on the json file.The reason I called all the markers is because I wanted to show all of them.  But now that I see it may cause some issues. I try too show the markers near user's location.

Comment: ok, and...? is it working? what is showing added log with `arrayListTemp` size?

Comment: When I type in the edit text `arrayListTemp` show the size according to the result . After backspace `arrayListTemp`  show the size of all location and its right. But what happens after click on results differs.t. for example in first try the list had one result and it zoomed on the right marker after I clicked on it. In another try the list had 4 results after I clicked nothing happened when I clicked on backspace,  it zoomed on the right marker. In another try I after clicked in zoomed in the wrong marker.